# Referencing one class object from another

Tags: python, tkinter

I've not used Python for a while... so I'm rusty. How do I reference one object from another class? (I'm a bit tired lol)

```
class UI_Controller(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'Kitty'

class PetPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        print(name) #<<<<< ??
```

full code - the part I want to print is 'print(name)' damn... I need to add more text now... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders... screw Flanders...

```
#has working frames, 
import tkinter as tk
fullscreen_fullscreen = False
import csv
import os
#locals()
#codePet project

class UI_Controller(tk.Tk):


    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, 'Code Pet')
        tk.Tk.geometry(self, '400x600')  # This is the size of the screen (in pixels)

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)



        if fullscreen_fullscreen:
            tk.Tk.wm_attributes(self, "-fullscreen", True)  # turn on and off fullscreen.

        self.frames = {}
        
        #below are the frames for the game
        for F in (PetPage,
                  MainGame):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

            frame.configure(background='ivory2'),

        self.grid_controller()
        self.show_frame(PetPage)

        global self.name = 'Kitty'
        self.hunger = '001'
        self.thirst = '001'
        self.tired = '001'
        self.poop = '001'
        self.play = '001'
        self.angry = '001'
        self.happy = '001'
        self.sad = '001'

        #here we have a list of main var's
        self.name = 'Kitty'
        self.hunger = '001'
        self.thirst = '001'
        self.tired = '001'
        self.poop = '001'
        self.play = '001'
        self.angry = '001'
        self.happy = '001'
        self.sad = '001'

        #if os.path.isfile("/memory") == True:
        try:
            self.load_creature(self)
        except:        self.write_creature_to_file(self)

        #the above is an example of a var stored and changed later. :)

    def load_creature(self, parent):
        with open('memory', "r") as f:
            list2 = []
            for item in f:
                number = 0
                while number < 1:
                    list2.append(item)
                    number += 1
            self.name = list2[0]
            self.hunger = list2[1]
            self.thirst = list2[2]
            self.tired = list2[3]
            self.poop = list2[4]
            self.play = list2[5]
            self.angry = list2[6]
            self.happy = list2[7]
            self.sad = list2[8]





    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()
    def grid_controller(self):
        #Alpha = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
        #print(Alpha[1])
        pass
        #taken out.


    def write_creature_to_file(self, parent):
        file = open('memory','w') 
        file.write('''%s
%s
%s
%s
%s
%s
%s
%s
%s''' % (self.name, self.hunger, self.thirst, self.tired,
             self.poop, self.play, self.angry, self.happy, self.sad))

        
        file.close()       




class PetPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        
        sysstatbutton = tk.Button(self, text='System Status',
                                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MainGame),
                                  height=2, width=12)
        sysstatbutton.place(x=20, y=180)

        #new text box

        mainText = tk.Text(self, height=8, width=40)
        mainText.place(x=20, y=400) #x is along, y is down, obviously lol
        #below inserts the text
        #mainText.insert(tk.END, "%s" % UI_Controller.name) #\n is line down, obvs ^^
        print(name)
        #

class MainGame(tk.Frame, UI_Controller):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        self.controller = controller
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        sysstatbutton = tk.Button(self, text='page 2',
                                  command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PetPage),
                                  height=2, width=12)
        sysstatbutton.place(x=20, y=180)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = UI_Controller()
    app.mainloop()
    app = None
    exit()






'''with open('memory', newline='') as inputfile:
            results = list(csv.reader(inputfile))
            #print(results) #[3]
            importlist = [parent.name, parent.hunger, parent.thirst, parent.tired,
                          parent.poop, parent.play, parent.angry,
                          parent.happy, parent.sad]
            number = 1
            name = importlist[0] 
            for i in importlist:#needswork
                importlist[number] = '{:03}'.format(int(results[number][0][0]) + int(results[number][0][1]) + int(results[number][0][2]))
                print(importlist[number])
                number = number + 1
'''







            
'''parent.hunger = results[0][0][0]
            parent.thirst = results[1][0][0]
            parent.tired = results[2][0][0]
            parent.poop = results[3][0][0]
            parent.play = results[4][0][0]
            parent.angry = results[5][0][0]
            parent.happy = results[6][0][0]
            parent.sad = results[7][0][0]
            #parent.sad = int(self.sad) + 5
            '''
```

Comment: `controller.name`

Comment: I know there are multiple ways of doing this... maybe I should move all the important variables somewhere else then reference/edit them?

Comment: What more is there than that? `print(controller.name)`, assuming you pass a `UI_Controller` object when calling `PetPage()`

Comment: AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Please show your full code. And you missed `super().__init__(args, kwargs)` in the `__init__` method of `UI_Controller`.

Answer (score 1):

The way you do it is to reference the object. Since `PetPage` is being given an instance of the controller, then `print(self.controller.name)` should work.

In your code, however, you're not defining `self.name` until after you create the instance of `PetPage`. You need to define `self.name` before you create any objects that use it.